# mysql aes_decrpyt returns incorrect value

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

Am using the following query in phpmyadmin on a XAMPP test environment:

SELECT AES_DECRYPT( AES_ENCRYPT('password1','secret'),'secret');

(see [MySQL Encryption-Decryption Example AES DECRYPT](http://coderlearner.com/MySQL_Encryption-Decryption_Example_AES_DECRYPT)

This query SHOULD return **password1**, however, it is actually returning **70617373776f726431**

Any suggestions as to why?

---

Database server

Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: 
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web server

Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $
PHP extension: mysqli

Answer (score 4):

It looks like phpMyAdmin is trying to be "helpful."

`70617373776f726431` is "password1" in hex.

When you pass data through `AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT())`, the character set information is lost, so MySQL considers the result to be "binary" rather than character data.  I suspect phpMyAdmin is making an incorrect assumption about how this data should be displayed to you.

Used in code, this would probably work fine exactly as it is, because your code isn't likely to incorrectly try to convert this to hex for you to see.  That's why, when you get something unexpected, and you aren't using the `mysql` command line client, you should always double-check using the official CLI to see what's *really* happening.

```
mysql> SELECT AES_DECRYPT( AES_ENCRYPT('password1','secret'),'secret');
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| AES_DECRYPT( AES_ENCRYPT('password1','secret'),'secret') |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| password1                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

You'll probably get the expected result in phpMyAdmin if you [cast](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) the output back to character data, but you shouldn't need to do this in your actual application.

```
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('password1','secret'),'secret') AS CHAR);
```

Of course, as a rule you shouldn't encrypt passwords, you should hash them.  You should only encrypt data that you *need* to be able to decrypt, and with passwords, that's generally not the case... and data you never store can't be compromised.

Comment: If you're usinng phpMyAdmin, there's a checkbox "Show binary contents as HEX" in the +Options section (right above query results). Toggle that off, click Go, and you will get plain text

Comment: Great. I looked the values up on the ascii table and  the result was indeed correct but not displaying right